# Functions of a single Random Variable

Tags: probability, functions, random-variables

I am having a hard time trying to understand functions of a random variable so I thought I would work through some problems. I had one in particular that I was stumped on:

> The RV X is $N(5,2)$ and Y = 2x+4. Find $\eta_ y,\sigma_y$, and $f_y(y)$

So far as I've understood the problem, we have $E[x] = 5$ and $\sigma = \sqrt(2)$. We can find the expectation of $Y = 2x+4$ through:
$$\eta_y = E[y] = E[2x+4] = 2E[x]+4 = 2*(5) + 4 = 14$$
By the same token, the approach to finding the standard deviation was:
$$\sigma_y^{2} = \sigma_y^{2}(2x+4) = 2^{2}\sigma^2(x) = 4*2 = 8.$$
Thus $\sigma_y = \sqrt(8)$

However, the only way I can think of in finding the PDF of y was solving for x (that is $\frac{y-4}{2}$ ) and plugging into the already known PDF of the normal distribution. However, I'm not sure that I'm correct in doing so. Furthermore, I'm not sure my approach in finding the standard deviation is also correct?
Thank you so much in advanced for your help, I really appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

I will prove a more general case of your problem. Suppose $X$ is a normal random variable with mean $\mu$ and variance $\sigma^2$. Let $a$ and $b$ be two constants ($b \not = 0$). Then, I claim that
$$
Y = a + b X
$$ 
has a normal distribution with mean $a + b \mu$ and variance $b^2 \sigma^2$. I prove this using the moment generating function approach.

Recall that a random variable's distribution is completely determined by its moment generating function (MGF). The MGF of $X$ is (by definition) 
$$
M_X(t) = \mathbf{E}(\exp{(tX)}) = \exp{(t \mu + \frac{1}{2} \sigma^2 t^2)}.
$$
And, the MGF of $Y$ is 
$$
M_Y(t) = \mathbf{E}(\exp{(t(a + bX)}) = \exp{(t a)} \mathbf{E}( \exp{((bt) X)} $$
Now, expanding and then plugging in $M_x(t)$. 
$$
M_Y(t) = \exp{(t a)} M_x(bt) = \exp{(t a)} \exp{( bt \mu + \frac{1}{2} \sigma^2 b^2 t^2)} = \exp{( t (b\mu + a) + \frac{1}{2} (\sigma b)^2 t^2)}.
$$
We recognize the expression on the righthand side as the moment generating function of a normal random variable with mean $b\mu + a$ and variance $(\sigma b)^2$.

Answer (score 0):

$\{ x | Y(x) \le \alpha \} = \{ x | x \le {\alpha-4 \over 2} \} $.

Hence $F_Y(\alpha) = F_X({\alpha-4 \over 2}  )$, and so
$f_Y(\alpha) = F_Y'(\alpha) = F_X'({\alpha-4 \over 2} ) { 1\over 2} = f_X({\alpha-4 \over 2} ) { 1\over 2}$.

Comment: So essentially solve for x in Y and plug that into the CDF. From there we can take the derivative to get the PDF, but all we need to worry about is taking the derivative of $\frac{y-4}{2}$?

Comment: Well, in the above context, the derivative of $\alpha \mapsto {\alpha-4 \over 2}$ :-).

Comment: What about the variance?

Comment: Can you figure out what the average must be given the expression for $f_Y$ above? It is a linear substitution in the integral. Similarly for the variance.

Comment: Note that $EY = 2EX + 4$ and $EY^2 = 4EX^2 + 16 E X + 16$.

Comment: I'm confused about your question?

Comment: If you know $f_Y$, then you can use a substitution formally compute $EY$ and $EY^2$ in terms of $EX, EX^2$. However, my last comment above is more straightforward to apply. You should end up with $EY = 2EX+4 = 14 $ and $E(Y-EY)^2  = 2^2 E(X-EX)^2 = 8$.

Answer (score -1):

In general one can compute the PDF of a ("nice") transformation $g(X)$ of a continuous random variable $X$ by calculating the CDF of $f(X)$ and then differentiating it. Thus if $Y=g(X)$ then $f_Y=\frac{dF_Y}{dy}$ where $F_Y(y)=P(Y \leq y)=P(g(X) \leq y)$. If $g$ is increasing then this is the same as $P(X \leq g^{-1}(y))=F_X(g^{-1}(y))$. If $g$ is decreasing then this is the same as $P(X \geq g^{-1}(y))=1-F_X(g^{-1}(y))$. If $g$ is neither (e.g. $g(x)=x^2$) then this is more complicated.

Comment: In this case, the CDF isn't very nice. I'm not sure the CDF of the normal distribution is exactly closed because it has the error function, right?

Comment: You don't have a closed form for $F_X$ (and so you don't have a closed form for $F_Y$ either), but you can differentiate $F_X(g^{-1}(y))$ easily enough by using the chain rule. Indeed $\frac{d}{dy} F_X(g^{-1}(y))=f_X(g^{-1}(y)) (g^{-1})'(y)$.

Comment: So we don't need to really worry about finding the derivative of the the non-closed $F_y$, but just the derivative of $g(y)$?

Comment: Essentially yes (but note that when we differentiated the $F_X$ became $f_X$, which we know!)

Comment: Ah! that makes sense! What about how I solved for the expectation and variance?

Comment: Those were both fine.